# Modal Dialog Over IFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am working on displaying a PopUp over an IFrame residing on same page.

Is it possible to overlay any div over IFrame?

I am currently using OpenModalDialog. Are there any other options available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to use the iframe shim method which involves putting an iframe inbetween the object you want on top, and the rest of the page.  You can layer these objects using the Z-Index css property, where objects with a higher Z-Index value are on top and objects with lower Z-Index values are on bottom.

This works when using standard HTML objects, but once you start using embeds such as Flash and Video, this technique will not always work as expected.